# how to send parameter in stateless4j trigger

Tags: java, triggers, state, fsm

I'm using stateless4j as a Finite State Machine library for my app, but I can't understand how to use parameters when firing triggers. I have the following code:

```
gameFSM.Configure(GameState.LOOKING_FOR_A_QUEST)
    .OnEntry(Actions.lookForQuest)
    .Permit(GameTrigger.QUEST_FOUND, GameState.JUDGING_QUEST);

gameFSM.Configure(GameState.JUDGING_QUEST)
    .OnEntry(Actions.judgeQuest)
    .Permit(GameTrigger.QUEST_ACCEPTED, GameState.INACTIVE) /* test */
    .Permit(GameTrigger.QUEST_DENIED, GameState.LOOKING_FOR_A_QUEST);

gameFSM.Configure(GameState.INACTIVE)
    .Permit(GameTrigger.START_LOOKING_FOR_QUESTS, GameState.LOOKING_FOR_A_QUEST);
```

Now I'm trying to create a parameter for the transition from `LOOKING_FOR_A_QUEST` to `QUEST_ACCEPTED`. I tried the following:

```
TriggerWithParameters1<Quest, GameState, GameTrigger> twp = gameFSM.SetTriggerParameters(GameTrigger.QUEST_FOUND, Quest);
```

But I not only don't understand how to `Fire` this trigger later, I also don't have a clue about what I'm creating with that snip. Can someone tell me how do I proceed with creating and firing that trigger with a parameter, like `gameFSM.trigger(GameTrigger.QUEST_FOUND, new Quest());`? Thanks!

**Bonus**: Why every single method in the `StateMachine` class can throw a suspicious and clueless `Exception`? I feel this library is so fluent, yet so terrible to use. Any recommendations?

Comment: https://github.com/oxo42/stateless4j  I have taken over maintenance of the project and have made as well as accepted quite a few changes.  Sending a parameter is still cumbersome, but the library at least feels good now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you ran into the same frustration that I did. I was able to pass the parameters by doing the following:

```
TriggerWithParameters1 twp = sm.setTriggerParameters(Trigger.D, java.util.Map.class);
sm.configure(State.D).permit(Trigger.A, State.A)
                     .onEntryFrom( twp, new Action1<Map>(){ 
                                            public void doIt(Map m) {
                                               System.out.println(m.toString());
                                            }
                                        }, Map.class);
Map data = new HashMap();
data.put("a", "1");
sm.fire(twp, data);
```

This approach seems overly complicated, but it does work.

Comment: It does indeed seem complicated, but it's the only way to ensure compile-time checks on parameter tyes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the parameterized actions if you use the `permitDynamic` forms in place of `permit`:

```
TriggerWithParameters1 twp = sm.setTriggerParameters(Trigger.D, java.util.Map.class);
sm.configure(State.D)
    .permitDynamic(
        twp,
        (m) -> State.A, 
        (m) -> System.out.println(m.toString())
    );

Map data = new HashMap();
data.put("a", "1");
sm.fire(twp, data);
```

The downside is that you lose the ability top generate the dot graph output